# os.getcwd() returns a slash (/)

Tags: python, macos, path, atom-editor, getcwd

I have a python 3.6 script that I wrote in Atom editor on macOS. The script uses os.getcwd() routinely and has always worked fine. I restarted my computer last night, updated the Atom packages, and suddenly it broke. Using a print statement, os.getcwd() is now only returning "/".

Tried on multiple scripts, all in different directories.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Expected: `/Users/kpaddock/Desktop/Python/SCID-Report-DRAFT`

Actual output: `/`

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I didn't look hard enough. Turns out `os.getcwd()` is not always accurate? Replaced with `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` and it works just fine.